# Run python .exe on any computer

Tags: python, executable

I created an .exe file using pyinstaller. What is does it, converts xlsx files into csv, deletes xlsx files, merges csv file and that is it.

What I want to do now is distribute this frozen .exe to other people who probably do not have python installed at their PC, and they are not tech savvy.

How can i make this csv.exe file in a way like spotify, which anyone can download and run with a click of a button?

Comment: I am not familiar with pyinstaller, but from what I have read it seems just sharing the exe file would work (on Windows).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776380/distributing-python-application-tutorials